# How to wrap certain words with html tag in a html structure

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html structure given below on the course's dates.

```
<div class="courses">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="start">01st Jan 2013</div>
      <div class="end">28th Jan 2013</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="start">03rd Jan 2013</div>
      <div class="end">10th Jan 2013</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap the date format like "st", "th" and "rd" with a SPAN tag like the following output structure. Wondering how to achieve this so that I can style it with css.

```
<div class="courses">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="start">01<span>st</span> Jan 2013</div>
      <div class="end">28<span>th</span> Jan 2013</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="start">03<span>rd</span> Jan 2013</div>
      <div class="end">10<span>th</span> Jan 2013</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a) Your HTML is malformed (missing `</div>` for the end date), b) you should really do this serverside when generating output. You can do it with a regular expression at runtime but that's really, really messy.

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/gz7rA/1/). modify as you need.

Comment: Thanks @Niels Keurentjes for pointing out. Mr_Green's script works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.start, div.end').each(function() {
    var date = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(date.replace(/(st|nd|rd|th)/, '<span>$1</span>'));
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GQM8n/)

Comment: short and simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set style `position:relative` for  `<span>` tag and move it to top using CSS.

DEMO: `jsfiddle.net/zqr2Q/`

Comment: I think the question was how to generate the `span` markup (for the purposes of styling, which was not presented as problematic).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var start = $('.start');
    var end = $('end');

    $.each(start,function(e,item){
        var text = $(item).html();
        var finalCh = text.substr(2,2);
        var newFinalCh = "<span class=\"yourClass\">" + finalCh + "</span>";
        var newText = text.replace(finalCh,newFinalCh);
        $(item).html(newText);
    });
```

Use this script after including jquery library

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("div .start:contains('st')").html().replace('st','<span>st</span');

alert($("div .start:contains('st')").html().replace('st','<span>st</span'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your own replacer() function:

```
function replacer(what, where) {
    where.html(where.html().replace(what, '<span>' + what + '</span>'));
}
```

Test here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NmHkh/6/